# Cannot locate element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, button, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with Python and Chromedriver to click on a "button" (not actually a button in the HTML, but looks like one on screen and is clickable). The HTML is below, I am trying to click on the one with the 'button-new' id.

```
<td class="read" colspan="4">
    <a href="#" id="button-read" onclick="formRead(); return false;" title="Read record from database" tabindex="1" class="button button-read">Read</a>
    <a id="button-new" title="Read new record from database" class="button button-new">New</a>
</td>
```

I have tried using:

```
new_button = driver.find_element_by_id("button-new")
new_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("A.button.button-new")
new_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="button-new"]')
```

followed by

```
new_button.click()
```

But I get the NoSuchElementException and it cannot locate it.

I've not had this problem with any other elements and not sure where I'm going wrong.

EDIT with solution:

I realised I needed to switch iframe

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("nested1"))
```

Comment: try `driver.find_element_by_id('button-read')`

Comment: @bhupathituraga This is also not located and there are two buttons next to one another: Read and New and I need to click New so I think even if it had located the button-read it wouldn't have helped me

Comment: please keep  more html or share the button url

Comment: Please debug and check, Before you click it Web page is loaded. Else, You need to use it with Explicit Wait.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_class_name("button.button-new")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, unfortunately you won't be able to access the webpage remotely to try yourself. I have used Explicit Wait in the command before and I can see that the webpage is fully loaded before I get the error. I'd also already tried searching by class name but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Use chrome CSS selector some times it works

Answer (score 0):

To make sure whether the element is being located try this:

```
new_button_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@id="button-new"]')
```

this will return a list because of using 'elements':

then check the length of the list, one good thing is it wont through an exception and also let you know whether the element is located.

Comment: It doesn't locate it at all (using this way, list length = 0) and without it I can't move on to the next steps of my automated testing

Comment: hmm , is this web content accessible remotely, so that i can give it a try

Comment: one thing i can say is there is nothing wrong with the xpath, so if the button is in the dom, i dont see why there is a location problem

Answer (score 0):

try to use it with `if` statement, maybe they put special a empty button to confuse us,

```
new_button = driver.find_element_by_id("button-new")
if new_button:
    new_button.click()
```

can you check with `find_elements_by_id` how many btn are there ?

```
btns = driver.find_elements_by_id("button-new")
print(btns)

# also we can check with # find_elements_by_id

btns = driver.find_elements_by_id("button-new")
if len(btns):
    new_button[0].click()
```

Comment: This means that the if statement does not get executed as there is no 'new_button'. I've tried getting them as a list too and the length is 0 as none are found.